# draw separately in 2 custom views in one class

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, view, draw

In IB, put 2 custom views into one window. I don't see any way to give them separate names. In Inspector-Info I had to use the same name, the class name, for both of them in the drop-down menu.  I tried

```
DrawRect:  NSRect bounds = [self bounds];       
[[NSColor greenColor] set]; 
[NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
```

which filled both custom views with green. But I would like to fill, draw, etc. independently in each custom view.  How can I address each view separately? Multiple custom views, later. Or does Cocoa require only one view per class?

This is probably trivial, but Google and the similar questions list here didn't come up with anything close. There's a lot of about multiple view controllers, but I don't need to switch views.

Comment: Looks like you are learning Cocoa programming by teaching yourself?  I think you should read a proper book on the subject or follow Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IB will show you the names of the classes that you can assign to an object. If you have only one custom class (eg. "myCustomClass") then it will only show that one in the drop-down menu.

I think the best solution to your problem, if you want tu use only one class, is to put the drawing code in two separate functions and assign each view an IBOutlet, then call the function from the controller class.

```
//Add this to your interface
NSNumber *myColor;

//Add/Edit the following functions
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)aRect
{
    //Some code...
    if ([myColor intValue]) [self drawGreen];
    else [self drawRed];
    //Some code...
}

- (void)drawGreen
{
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];       
    [[NSColor greenColor] set]; 
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
}

- (void)drawRed
{
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];       
    [[NSColor redColor] set]; 
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
}

- (void)drawRedOrGreen:(int)aColor
{
    myColor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:aColor];
}
```

You have to add the following two lines to your controller's interface

```
    IBOutlet myCustomClass *customView1;
    IBOutlet myCustomClass *customView2;
```

And you have to set each view's color.
This will set it when it loads for the first time.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [customView1 drawRedOrGreen:1]; //Green
    [customView2 drawRedOrGreen:0]; //Red
}
```

This way each view will be coloured differently.

An alternative solution would be to create two separate custom classes (eg. "myCustomClass1" and "myCustomClass2") which would have their own drawing code...

Comment: Thank you, but I think I didn't explain clearly enough: the problem is to draw red things in one view and a green things in the other view, not to draw one set or the other in both views, which is what the code above will do. aRect will address both custom views in myCustomClass, which you point out about the drop-down menu. (new para) I can't see a way to address each custom view individually. How would you use IB Outlets? (new para) I'm afraid that Cocoa does permit only one custom view per class.

Comment: Please forgive my clumsiness in adding comments. I tried 2 spaces-return to get new lines, and pressing escape twice to get new paragraphs. Instead, the website took my edits and then I tried to finish correcting them.

Comment: The code should draw only green in one, and red in the other.
I think I understood what you ment the first time around.
I edited the code to be more descriptive of my solution,
maybe now you will understan what I ment.

Comment: I found some time to make you an example. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4556129/Stack%20Overflow/ColoredViewsDemo.zip

Comment: Wow! That was fast.  Many thanks. I tried compiling and ran into some errors. I think you coded in Xcode 4 and I'm using Xcode 3.3, so I created a new project and dragged the .h and .m files into it. (This has worked before.) At the moment I'm fighting with "@synthesize  NSNumber *_myColor;--- expected ; before * token." "@property (strong) NSNumber *myColor;" had to be changed to "(copy)". More soon. I'm concerned because I don't see a way to tie each custom view to its instance in IB, only the class.

Comment: Here I tried to make a XCode 3.3 compatible version https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4556129/Stack%20Overflow/ColoredViewsDemovXcode33.zip

Comment: It runs! It's very clear and nicely done. You have answered my question of how to address each custom view individually very well. I was unable to find an answer anywhere else during many hours of searching. Thank you very much; you're the most helpful responder I have seen in any of the online forums. (par) A couple of minor points: I made a few changes in 3.3 Project Settings (if you like, I can send the details), and I'm surprised to see you start with NSDocument rather than NSObject (why?).

Comment: Sure, post the link so that future readers can see how you solved it.
I started with NSDocument because it is the defaul controller class in Xcode 4, an to be honest it doesn't matter what the class of the controller is. (NSDocument adds default saving behaviour to your program, that's all)

Comment: Ah. Default controller: one more difference while stepping back to Xcode 3.3. The minor cleanups were associated with using OSX 10.6 rather than 10.8.

Comment: (time ran out, here's the rest) To fix errors and warnings, in Project>Edit Project Settings>Build:    1.Base SDK, macosx to 10.6.    2.Search for "10.8", change to 10.6.   3.It runs with Warnings "Wuninitialized...", but to clean up, search for "Uninitialized Automatic Variables" and uncheck.

Comment: You use "if ([sender tag] == 1)" at the start. How do you find the tag # for a custom view in IB? (I'm thinking of multiple views.) After selecting one, I didn't find its tag number in the Inspector. In Google, I couldn't find any help, either.

Comment: Oops! I just realized you're looking at the button's tag number. And of course you can see on the screen which button is on top of which custom view.

Comment: Playing around, I put an NSLog statement at the end of the drawRect. It looks like drawRect sets the colors in both custom views multiple times, initially and after each Toggle. Any idea why this would be? In other programs I've seen that drawRect does its thing once only.- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
 int j=[myColor intValue];
    if (j) [self drawGreen];
    else [self drawRed];
 count++;
 NSLog(@"myColor = %i",j);
}

Comment: Because the view gets redrawn when you hit the button, when the button is animated, and after the animation finishes + i manually tell it to refresh the whole view with "setNeedsDisplay:". If you look at the draw funcion in the View, then you will notice that is goes something like "drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect" the dirtyRect means that the draw function doesn't draw the whole view, but just the part that changed, to save memory and processing power. If you would move the buttons outside of the views, then it would call drawRect only once.

Comment: Yes indeed, moving the buttons outside of the custom views, it calls drawRect only once, as expected, both at startup and after clicking the buttons. But with buttons on top of the custom views, it seems like the system is calling draw rect successively for a while, until it somehow gets into a wait state,  both at startup and after clicking the buttons.

Comment: "it seems like the system is calling draw rect successively for a while" Because it calls drawRect: when the buttons get drawn, when the window gets drawn, when the other view gets drawn, and it draws it self one. Basically a view will call drawRect whenever something in contact with it changes.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. As a small token of appreciation, I'd like to send you a revised version of the program which has some small changes and adds text.  Contact me at my published email address doggerel89@yahoo.com.    Your big contribution to my progress was the IBOutlets in Custom Views. I had no idea they exist and provide a means of controlling them.